# How to update related entities in Symfony2

Tags: file, symfony, upload, entities

My situation is this, firstly there is a entity Person which have a OneToMany relationship with the entity Face (and of course the other way around with ManyToOne), and each time I update the Person entity I might add some extra Face entities to the Person. Basically it looks like this:

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Face", mappedBy="person", cascade={"persist"})
 */
private $faces;

...

/** 
 * @ORM\PrePersist()
 * @ORM\PreUpdate()
 */
public function preUpload()
{   
    foreach ($this->images as $image) {
        if (null === $image) {
            break;
        }   

        $face = new Face();
        $face->setPerson($this);
        $face->setImagePath(sha1(uniqid(mt_rand(), true)));
        $this->addFace($face);
    }   
}
```

This works as expected when I do persist the Person with some Face entities for the first time, but when I try to update a existing Person and add more Face entities I cannot make them persist, everything that should happen does, except that no new Face entities is persisted.

Hope somebody has been in the same situation and can give me some advice, peace out!

Comment: In the situation that doesn't create the update, can you confirm that any iterations of the for loop get past the `if(null === $image)`?

Comment: As I said it does everything EXCEPT persisting the related entities (it even uploads the files in another method), one solution that actually works is to flush twice on updating a Person, then it persists the newly added Face entities also, however this doesn't feel like the Symfony way to solve it...

Comment: As far as my understanding is concerned, a update of the Person entity does NOT trigger any persist cascade on the related entities, however from what I stated above they do persist after a second flush, it would be fantastic if somebody could explain how to do this the correct way though.

Comment: Perhaps try flushing the Face object in your preUpload function prior to `$this->addFace($face);`

Comment: But would it be natural to access the entity manager within the preUpload method which lives within a entity? I think that's bad practice and I'm maybe wrong trying to add related entities within another entity in the first place...

Answer (score 0):

I have a comparable project, where a survey has questions and each Question has an Image.

I followed the [docs here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/file_uploads.html) and for updating the related entity I moved all the logic to that Entity, which wuold be "Face" in your case. Everything works fine and my controller looks like this:

```
...

$survey->preUpload();
$questions = $survey->getQuestions();
    foreach ($questions as $question)
    {
        $question->preUpload();
    }

$em->persist($survey);
$em->flush();

...
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: There is no question it can be done in various ways, as I mention in the comments, just adding a second flush to the update action, that solves the problem and indeed does persist the newly added records, but my wondering is more about WHY Symfony2 does not run any inserts when new entities has been added in this manner, is it about the timing of PreUpdate() which does not allow adding any new entities, doesn't Symfony2 change the state of the entity in this particular time, I don't know...

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify a cascade persist policy even on the other side of the relation. It's not automatically bidirectional.

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Person", inversedBy="faces", cascade={"persist"})
 */
```

Comment: Do you have any explanation why that would solve my problem? Read my comments on the question, it does persist the Face entities when the Person get's persisted the first time, but when updating it doesn't.

Comment: Because when uploading, you're persisting the Face entity. This does trigger a cascading persist on the Person entity, if you'll add it as I was suggesting.

Comment: It does never explicitly persist any Face entities, as you can see the only method called is addFace(), this does only append the list of faces that should be associated with that particular Person, adding the cascade option to the Face entity doesn't change anything actually. And yes I've tried it :)

Comment: So, you need a persist inside the addFace method, if you don't persist it will never make to the DB!

Comment: I hope you read all the other comments and you know that the faces do persist and gets added to the database on creating a new Person entity with associated faces, and still if I do flush twice on updating a existing Person with newly added Face entities they do get added to the database.

Comment: It may depends on what you really do. Can you post your code that breaks?